Using serial port on android qemu
I'm trying to test the serial port functionality on android studio's emulator. What I'm currently doing:

On host side

I created a pair of virtual ports com3 and com4 using com0com
I tested them using a pair of realterm instances
I leave only one realterm instance connected to com4


On emulator side

I use aosp image
I start using emulator -avd Small_Phone_API_35 -qemu -serial COM3
I choose baud 9600 8n1 no flow control when the dialog pops up to setup the serial port
I additionally execute adb root and adb shell setenforce 0


On software side

I use https://github.com/licheedev/Android-SerialPort-API to test
I verified that SerialPort is created with the same baud rate, parity, data bits, stop bits as I choose when the emulator starts and as configured in realterm



Some kind of connection exists, since when the emulator starts, realterm lights up dcd and dsr statuses. But:

When I try to send data from emulator to host, realterm doesn't receive it. But the counter displayed by adb shell cat /proc/tty/driver/serial increases.
When I try to send data from host to emulator, emulator freezes and is then killed with message detected a hanging thread 'QEMU2 main loop'.

Notably, if I set flow control to hardware in the emulator dialog, cts status also lights up in realterm, but nothing else changes.
I tried different port settings, I tried connecting to tcp instead of com3, I tried using putty instead of realterm, but the end result doesn't change. Is there anything I can do to make the data flow correctly?
